# iTEBD real time evolution for 3-body time evolution operator

Tags: condensed-matter, simulations, spin-chains, tensor-network

I am trying to implement the iTEBD algorithm for real-time evolution of the PXP model. Here, $P$ is the projector onto the ground state, and $X$ is the Pauli spin matrices.

I know for the 2-body case, following Fig. 3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0605597, one multiplies by $\lambda_B$ on both sides , and multiplies by the inverse later on to find the new $\Gamma_A$ and $\Gamma_B$.

My question is, how is the above step modified for the 3-body case? Does one use $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$ as the matrices on either side? In this case, how would one go on to find the matrices $\Gamma_A$ and $\Gamma_B$?

Comment: The reason that there is A and B is that there are two different patterns of non-overlapping unitaries when trotterizing. You have three such groups, you will need A, B, and C. Or you block terms until you have an effective two-body problem. This will always work, though it is not the most efficient nor the most elegant way.

Comment: Could you please explain where you get the A,B and C from? To my knowledge, the tensors A and B would be determined by the size of the unit cell for the initial state. In my case, as I want to evolve from a Neel ordered state, my unit cell consists if 2 sites, and so I assumed we would have only 2 tensors A and B?

Comment: Also, if possible could you point me to some reference or literature for the two-body effective problem method you have mentioned above?

Comment: The periodicity of the ansatz is not only determined by the initial state, but also by the evolution you do. If you start with an AFM and have a 3-body Hamiltonian, you might need 6 different tensors. Or you block.

Comment: For the blocking, this is straightforward: If you block two spins in one, the Hamiltonian can be rewritten as a sum of 2-body NN interactions.

Comment: Could you clarify what AFM stands for?

Comment: Antiferromagnet. (Neel, in your case.)